# A geometry Sector Solver, Value finder for my calculator's micropython

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I made a program for my calculator for A levels that acquires the value of the angle and radius of a sector and gives:

1. Area of Sector
2. Area of inner Triangle
3. Arc Length
4. Chord Area
5. Chord Length
6. Sector Perimeter

I need some advice on compacting and making it more efficient, it would be also nice to have some coding tricks.

Disclaimer: my calculator uses [**micropython**](https://micropython.org/) which lacks alot of functions, and modules however some functions from `math` work, check the documentary about it to confirm.

```py
from math import pi, sin

def input_pi_replacer(prompt):
    return float(eval(input(prompt).replace("pi", str(pi))))

def stopper():
    stop_or_continue = input("Stop?: ")
    if stop_or_continue == "x":
        raise SystemExit  

print("Sector Quantities\nCalculator:\n")
C_Factor = 0
Area = 0
B = 0
while True:
    C_Factor = 0
    Area = 0

    Unit = ""
    # + = degrees , - = radians
    while Unit not in ['+', '-']:
        Unit = input("For Deg, enter '+',\nFor Rad, enter '-'\n: ")
        if Unit == "+":
            C_Factor = pi/180
            break
        elif Unit == "-":
            C_Factor = 180/pi
            break
        elif Unit == ".":
            raise SystemExit
    # R = Radius, A = theta/angle in deg/rads, C_Angle = Converted Angle, C_Factor = Conversion Factor of Angle

    R = input_pi_replacer("\nEnter Radius: ")
    A = input_pi_replacer("Enter Theta/Angle: ")

    if Unit == "+":
        C_Angle = A * C_Factor
        Angle_In_Deg = A
    elif Unit == "-":
        C_Angle = A
        Angle_In_Deg = A * C_Factor

    print()
    Sector_Area = 1/2 * (R**2) * C_Angle
    Triangle_Area = 1/2 * (R**2) * sin(C_Angle)
    Arc_Length = R * C_Angle
    Chord_Area = Sector_Area - Triangle_Area
    Chord_Length = 2 * R * sin(C_Angle/2)
    Perimeter_Sector = 2 * R + Arc_Length
    print("Area of Sector\n= ", Sector_Area)
    print("Area of inner Triangle\n= ", Triangle_Area)
    print("Arc Length\n= ", Arc_Length)
    print("Chord Area\n= ", Chord_Area)
    print("Chord Length\n= ", Chord_Length)
    print("Sector Perimeter\n= ", Perimeter_Sector)
    print()
    stopper()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Naming

Variable and function names should be `snake_case`, not `This_Format` or `This`. `Uppercase` and `PascalCase` are reserved for class names.

## Checking inside lists vs strings

If you're checking for a single character, it's better to use a string rather than a list. Have a look:

```
if unit in "+-":
    ...
```

## The walrus operator

If you're using `python-3.8` you can use the walrus operator. It's another way of saying assignment expressions. It's a way to assign a variable within an expression. In your case, you can utilize the walrus operator to assign `input` to a variable, and use that. Have a look:

```
while unit := input("For Degrees, enter '+',\nFor Radians, enter '-'\n: "):
    if unit in "+-":
        ...
```

So `unit` is assigned whatever the output of the `input`  call is.

## Unneeded function

If your function is simply an `input` call, you don't really need it. Just put it at the end of the `while` loop.

## Ternary operators

You can use these to greatly shorten the length of your code. It's an easier way to assign values based on conditions. Take a look at the final code to see what I'm saying.

## f-strings

You should use `f""` to directly implement variables in your strings. It's a cool feature that keeps you from having to `+` or call a `.format` on your strings. Have a look:

```
print(f"Area of Sector = {sector_area}")
print(f"Area of inner Triangle = {triangle_area}")
...
```

## Final code

After all these suggestions, you code would look something like this:

```
from math import pi, sin

def input_pi_replacer(prompt):
    return float(eval(input(prompt).replace("pi", str(pi))))

print("Sector Quantities Calculator:\n")
while True:

    while unit := input("For Degrees, enter '+',\nFor Radians, enter '-'\n: "):
        if unit in "+-.":
            if unit == ".":
                raise SystemExit
            c_factor = (pi / 180) if unit == "+" else (180 / pi)
            break

    radians = input_pi_replacer("\nEnter Radius: ")
    angle = input_pi_replacer("Enter Theta/Angle: ")

    c_angle = angle * c_factor if unit == "+" else angle

    print()
    sector_area = 1 / 2 * (radians ** 2) * c_angle
    triangle_area = 1 / 2 * (radians ** 2) * sin(c_angle)
    arc_length = radians * c_angle
    chord_area = sector_area - triangle_area
    chord_length = 2 * radians * sin(c_angle / 2)
    perimeter_sector = 2 * radians + triangle_area

    print(f"Area of Sector = {sector_area}")
    print(f"Area of inner Triangle = {triangle_area}")
    print(f"Arc Length = {arc_length}")
    print(f"Chord Area = {chord_area}")
    print(f"Chord Length = {chord_length}")
    print(f"Sector Perimeter = {perimeter_sector}")
    print()

    if input("Stop?: ").lower() == "x":
        raise SystemExit
```

Comment: hmm walrus operator, thats new, and fyi micropython doesn't support f" strings, its sad i know, however thanks for the rest!!